# Subcategory product image and link not showing on display block

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have created a subcategory called Housekeeping Uniforms and divided into two more subcategories - Stock Housekeeping Uniforms and Custom Housekeeping Uniforms.
Both subcategories show on the category tree on the front end, but only the image and link of the Stock Housekeeping Uniforms subcategory shows on the Display block.

The link to the page is: 
https://www.jauniforms.com/products/housekeeping-uniforms.html

I have a mirror subcategory on the site on a different page and this page show both images on the display block.

https://www.jauniforms.com/products/hotel-uniforms/housekeeping-uniforms.html

Any advise on how to make this work. Thank you!

We work on magento 1.9 version

Comment: can you share your skype

Comment: Hello Sourav. I can't figure out what is going wrong. Like I said the subcategory shows on the tree and if I click on it, the link works correctly, but the display image for custom Housekeeping Uniforms is not showing on the display block

Comment: skype: eduarto_5

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the subcategory completely and create it again. Only then the issue was resolved. Now the images on the display block are showing.